# Creating 2D animations using 3D characters

Tags: animation, camera, 2d

I am new to Blender and am just learning the basics. I want to create 2D animations using a single character. The 2D animations would portray different angles of the character. Hence, I thought creating a single 3D character and somehow using that in 2D would save me the work of redrawing the character again and again.

Is something like this possible using Blender? Or is it better to simply create the character in 2D multiple times with different angles?

Comment: Some reference (image / anim gif) would be helpful to share in your question.

Answer (score 1):

Depends what you're good at. Of course Blender produces 2D images, and people have often done what you describe, so it's possible. 
Freestyle helps you outline objects if you want to go for the hand-drawn feel and there are tons of toon shaders out there for drawing like colors.
You can also use grease pencil in Blender (it was vastly improved in 2.80) if you'd rather stick to pure 2D.